# why Static constructors not called first and i got exception when use declared variable?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, constructor, static-constructor

From MSDN

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced

[MSDN Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors)

Now came to my problem:

```
public static class DateFormat
{
    private static List<string> DateFormats = new List<string>();

    public static string DateSeparator  { get; set; } = "/";

    public static string Current { get; set; } = DateFormats[1]; // error here

    static DateFormat()
    {
        DateFormats.Add("yyyy{0}MM{0}dd HH{1}mm{1}ss");
        DateFormats.Add("yyyy{0}MM{0}dd hh{1}mm{1}ss");
    }
}
```

As you see above when calling `DateFormats[1]` error

> "The type initializer for 'DateFormat' threw an exception."

Is constructor should calling static constructor first?  so that dictionary will filled then any call to variable which use it will be ok.

Comment: A static constructor is used to initialize any static data !! Initialize first then populate

Comment: Man see mSDN above. it says static constructor called first.

Comment: Note that you can also just inline initialise that list and not use the constructor at all.

Comment: Yes it says and it happens what exactly it says. It is called first.

Comment: Liyod i know that now. but static constructor not called first. did i made something wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behaviour is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors

Specifically, this section:

> If static field variable initializers are present in the class of the static constructor, they will be executed in the textual order in which they appear in the class declaration **immediately prior to the execution of the static constructor**.

Since  static field variable initializers are indeed present, they will be initialised BEFORE the static constructor, which is why you are seeing that error:

```
public static string Current { get; set; } = DateFormats[1];
```

will be executed before

```
static DateFormat()
{
    DateFormats.Add("yyyy{0}MM{0}dd HH{1}mm{1}ss");
    DateFormats.Add("yyyy{0}MM{0}dd hh{1}mm{1}ss");
}
```

and thus of course, the `DateFormats` list is still empty at the point that `DateFormats[1]` is executed.

To solve this, just initialise `Current` in the static constructor:

```
public static class DateFormat
{
    static DateFormat()
    {
        DateFormats.Add("yyyy{0}MM{0}dd HH{1}mm{1}ss");
        DateFormats.Add("yyyy{0}MM{0}dd hh{1}mm{1}ss");

        Current = DateFormats[1];
    }

    private static List<string> DateFormats = new List<string>();

    public static string DateSeparator { get; set; } = "/";

    public static string Current { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @asdk1200000: the solution to any problem with mixing initializers and constructors is simple: don't mix them. Write everything in the constructor instead. In the background, the compiler has to move all initializer code to the constructor anyway, so you may as well be explicit about it.

Comment: so if there's initializers then static constructor will never hit first. ? is this true

Comment: @asdk1200000: On the IL level, initializers don't exist. The compiler takes initializers and whatever you wrote in the (static) constructor and arranges these into one constructor body, with the initializers happening in textual order and then whatever you put in the constructor body explicitly. While this is all documented and predictable, relying on it just makes your code brittle and harder to understand. As soon as you have something too complicated to handle just for initializers alone, you're better off moving everything into the constructor explicitly so it's clear what's happening.

Comment: But please, when i debbuging something i need to know.. because this is first time in my life to use static constructors. so if there's only one static field which initialized the static constructor will not called first ? or the field that will called if it initialized the static consturctor not called. ?

Comment: @asdk1200000 It happens in exactly the order described in the documentation that I quoted. Not sure how I can elaborate on that; it's about as clear as it could be: All static fields (if any) will be initialised before the static constructor, in the order in which they occur in the code file.

Answer (score 1):

This is how all syntactic sugar is "translated":

```
static DateFormat()
{
    DateFormats = new List<string>();
    DateSeparator = "/";
    Current = DateFormats[1]; // at this point DateFormats is empty
    DateFormats.Add("yyyy{0}MM{0}dd HH{1}mm{1}ss");
    DateFormats.Add("yyyy{0}MM{0}dd hh{1}mm{1}ss");
}
```

Don't mix inline initialization and code inside constructor. It's a headache.
Especially if class members depends on each other. This is true for instance constructors too.